# Role of transport layer in UWSNs

Tags: networking, wireless, unetstack

How and exactly where transport layer comes into picture, especially when a sensor node sends data to other sensor node? (Also can you suggest some resources to study about data transfer in UWSNs)

I have gone through few research papers, but didn't get the clear understanding of role of transport layer while sending data among sensor nodes.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of the OSI model, the [transport layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_layer) provides end-to-end connection-oriented communication, reliability, flow control, and multiplexing, typically over a multi-hop network.

For UnetStack, the [transport service](https://unetstack.net/handbook/unet-handbook_transport_service.html) provides a similar functionality, with end-to-end reliability and fragmentation/reassembly for large datagrams, potentially over a multi-hop network. It may also support connection-oriented services for data streaming.